# bootstrap link is not correct

Tags: python, html, css, django

My web site is not set bootstrap design correctly.I wrote in index.html,

```
<html lang="ja">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="/static/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/index.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/bootflat/css/bootflat.min.css">
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  </head>
      ・
　　　 ・
```

in settings.py

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'bootflat.github.io'), ]
```

When I click href="/static/css/bootstrap.min.css",404 error happens.
Directory structure is like

```
-PythonServer
  -PythonServer
  -logic
   -static
    -index.css
   -templates
    -index.html
  -boolflat.github.io
  -bower_components
```

I think I set STATIC_URL correctly so I do not know why  bootstrap design is not set.What is wrong in my code?How should I fix this?

Comment: Side note, you should never hard code your static files' path. Instead, use `{% static 'path/to/staticfiles' %}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base.html:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

...your css...

```
{% block head %}

{% endblock head %}
```

pay attention the order is important you need first add bootstrap and then your css in order all your css will work ok.

Answer (score 0):

For adding static files to your project,the process is

- create a new directory called static inside your project folder
- Inside that directory ,you can add your images folder,or whatever static content.
- you have to add this directory path to project's settings.py file and one static_variable is also added.
- For adding this to the html file,you will need template tagging i.e. `{% load staticfiles  %}`. This line will go after the doctype html declaration  This will load your static content to your html file .
- It is always good to use template tagging in your src or href attribute 
  For ex - `<img src={% static 'images/img.png' %}`

So, as per you code ,there are two main points to be include ,firstly for adding any static content ,you have to include `{% load staticfiles %}` and second thing if your static contents are in the folder named static ,the path needs to be added to project settings.py file like `STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')` the 'static ' here refers to your main static folder in the project directory where all your static content is there.